# How to dispose of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, arduino

I was looking at some arduino code which said :

```
std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
```

Normally a unique pointer is created using make_unique.

So I was wondering what I need to do to dispose of this pointer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) is introduced in c++14, before that, the systax you posted is the standard way to create a unique_ptr. You don't need to do anything to dispose the raw pointer and unique_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do anything. This code does almost the same thing as `make_unique`. I'd recommend you not to write code like this yourself (`make_unique` is better), but if you can't change this line, you are unlikely to notice the difference.

When `unique_ptr` is initialized with a raw pointer and when the expression is a bit more complicated than in this case, memory leak can occur. `make_unique` prevents that possibility.

With `shared_pointer`s it's also slightly less efficient to initialize it with a raw pointer than to use `make_shared`.

Comment: This technique isn't any less efficient or buggy, as long as every `new` is immediately given to a named `unique_ptr` in a variable definition that does nothing else. The bugs come up when creating a `unique_ptr` within some more complicated expression.

Comment: Right, I'll rephrase my answer.